# MDX Retention Rate

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I am new to OLAP and I have a pretty tricky assignment that I am not sure is possible in MDX:

I work for an insurance company and I have been asked to provide a Retention Rate calculation to compare the number of policies we have kept from one time period to another.

The data in our fact table consists of a month-end snapshots of each our policies and there is a flag to indicate whether they are currently active at that time.

So, in plain English, the steps to find the Retention Rate from December 2014 to December 2015 would be:

1. Get the set of active policy IDs as of December 2014 (set #1)
2. Get the set of active policies as of December 2015 that have the SAME policy ID as set #1 (set #2)
3. Divide set #2 by set #1 to get the Retention Rate

I am just not sure if it is possible to compare specific IDs from two different sets like that in MDX.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something one would normally use MDX for, since it involves a condition at the detail level (PolicyID), and MDX is all about data in aggregate.

However, if you are willing and able to add a flag to your fact table/view it can be done.  To address your exact question, you could simply add a bit (or int) flag into your fact table.   For each record, the flag would be true (1) if the PolicyID is active now AND was active a year ago, and false (0) if it was not.

Then you can add a new measure to your cube that counts "retained policies", which is just the sum of the flag you just added, and then you can easily divide one measure by another.

If your needs are more complex than this one instance, there might be ways to add more complex data, but the point is that you have to create a way for your cube to be able to compare aggregations.